# Momentjs in Polymer WebComponent - global is undefined

Tags: polymer, momentjs, web-component

I want to use momentjs in a webcomponent for a custom card in home-assistant

When I try to import the library, I get the following error:

> Cannot set property 'moment' of undefined

```
import './lib/moment.min.js';

class ContentCardExample extends HTMLElement {
    ...
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed moment from npm, you should import it as:

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment.js';
```

and include any locales like this (in case you need them:

```
import 'moment/src/locale/es.js';
```

Comment: I just downloaded it and added it to a subdirectory. I also tried using unpkg but both resulted in the same error. I don't think how I installed it would make a difference though ... . To me it appears that moment is defined as a property on the the global property which seems not to be there in a web component.

Comment: Davalos: I also tried your suggestion but then I'm having troubles because of all the imports in moment.js do not end with a .js extension does chrome has 404's for all those imports. I hope that makes any sense?